# Android Recycler view not updating

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-actionbar, android-softkeyboard

I have a recycler view that fills with data at the application's start. It fills well everytime, but the recycler view doesn't update everytime. Clicking the action bar to open the keyboard refreshes it.

I also notify the recycler view for update after all of the data has finished loading.

1. How should I update/refresh it?
2. Is recycler view not updating a bug or something?

I'm gonna add code and XML layouts if needed.

refresh/notify code:

```
// Inflate
new java.util.timer().schedule(
    () -> {
        runOnUiThread(()->{
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

    }, 1000
);
```

Comment: Add the refresh code

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: added my refresh code

Comment: Because if I don't, I get an error for not calling the view in the thread that created it.

Comment: The error says "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check following example to refresh `recyclerview` in every 1 second.

```
Handler timerHandler;
timerHandler = new Handler();

Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 1000);
```

Comment: Will try it out! Thanks